# Future Method cannot be called from batch

Tags: batch, future

I have written a batch class which triggers in after update trigger on the object. This Afterupdate trigger in turn calls the future method. After running the batch class i realise that Salesforce does not allow to call future method from a batch class. I added AllowsCallouts option in batch class definition but it does not help as the future method has been called from the trigger and not form the batch class itself. Any suggestion here?

Comment: Have you tried using a Queueable instead of a future method?